# How to specifically name each value in a list of tuples in python?

Tags: python-3.x

The Tuple_list prints out something like "`[ (2000, 1, 1, 1, 135) , (2000, 1, 1, 2, 136) ) , etc...]`" and I can't figure out how to assign "year,month,day,hour,height" to every tuple in the list..."

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as read:
        pre_list = list()

        for line in read.readlines():
            remove_symbols = line.strip()
            make_list = remove_symbols.replace(" ", ", ")
            pre_list += make_list.split('()')

        Tuple_list = [tuple(map(int, each.split(', '))) for each in pre_list]

        for n in Tuple_list:
            year, month, day, hour, height = Tuple_list[n][0], Tuple_list[
                n][1], Tuple_list[n][2], Tuple_list[n][3], Tuple_list[n][4]

        print(month)

        return Tuple_list
swag = read_file("VIK_sealevel_2000.txt")
```

Comment: Could you please add an explaination to your code. It will help us to understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: May be `namedtuple` from `collections` module will help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ["Named tuples"](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html?highlight=named#collections.namedtuple) is what you are looking for.

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple                                      

In [2]: Measure = namedtuple('Measure', ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'height'])        

In [3]: m1 = Measure(2005,1,1,1,4444)   

In [4]: m1
Out[4]: Measure(year=2005, month=1, day=1, hour=1, height=4444)
```

Comment: Look at the example. The list of fields must be a list not a string.

Comment: I applied your example into my code but it gives me an error "`TypeError: __new__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'month', 'day', 'hour', and 'height'`"